# Convert percentage margin into percentage markup without knowing the revenue.

Tags: percentages

So client has asked me to add an option to their website where they can apply **margin markup** instead of **regular markup**.

But all the formulas that I seem to be reading seem to know the revenue value in order to calculate the margin.

But I don't know the revenue.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/margin#how-to-calculate-profit-margin

This calculator in the link above does not know the revenue, and simply calculates the revenue.

```
For example £1
Margin: 30%
Revenue: £1.43
```

So I need to know the formula that makes this 43% regular markup.

```
To arrive at a 10% margin, the markup percentage is 11.1%

To arrive at a 20% margin, the markup percentage is 25.0%

To arrive at a 30% margin, the markup percentage is 42.9%

To arrive at a 40% margin, the markup percentage is 80.0%

To arrive at a 50% margin, the markup percentage is 100.0%
```

Can this be made into a formula somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{1- p_{\text{margin}}} = 1 + p_{\text{markup}}
$$
where $p_{\text{margin}}$ is the margin divided by $100~\%$; and $p_{\text{markup}}$ is the markup divided by $100~\%$.

Comment: So `=1/(1-40%)` = `1.66666667`... i'm struggling to understand this formula can you help me out, maybe use operators. Lets say £1 is our unit cost, and we want add 30% margin, which should equal £1.43

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the given data. My formula works for all of the other numbers. For example,
$$
\frac{1}{1-0.1} = 1.1111
$$
which corresponds to the first data example

Comment: Wait you are on to something here! Thank you so much :-)